# Magento Subtotal error with discount code and Payal Integral

Tags: magento, paypal, discount

I've a serious bug on a magento website and 0 idea how to resolve it...

I made a basic discount code : - 10% on item.

But when I want to paypal with Paypal Evolution, total is wrong ...

A small example below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOttu.png

As you can see, total is **58,90**

If I check paypal log :

```
        [L_BUTTONVAR0] => subtotal=54.54
        [L_BUTTONVAR1] => tax=9.82
        [L_BUTTONVAR2] => shipping=0.00
        [L_BUTTONVAR3] => invoice=100017818
        [L_BUTTONVAR4] => address_override=true
        [L_BUTTONVAR5] => currency_code=EUR
        [L_BUTTONVAR6] => buyer_email=
        [L_BUTTONVAR7] => discount=6.55
```

So 54.45+9.82-6.55 = **57.72**, total is wrong...

Thank you for your time, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you account for the amount that Paypal takes from every purchase? I believe it's 3% + 30 cents, or something like that

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but it's nothing like that. Order without discount works fine and total in paypal log is exactly the same as total in magento backend...

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Best of luck.

Comment: Which magento version are you using? Is the discount applied before or after tax?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.0.1 and tax applied after discount.